# SetTimeOut inside a Javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, coffeescript

I have this code snippet , basically I want to add some interval in between calling  `myfunc` for each element in `myCol` .

```
         Promise.all(
                _.map(myCol, (o) ->
                  setTimeout =>
                    myfunc(o)
                    10000)
              )
```

With above implementation ,  `myfunc` is getting called without any interval

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the map function is setting the timeouts all at once. What you need to do is have the map function return after (n+1) lots of 10 seconds where n is the index of the element in `myCol`.

As I don't have `_.map`, I'll show you with `array.prototype.forEach`:

```js
const myCol = [1,2,3,4];
const myFunc = console.log;

myCol.forEach((o,i) => setTimeout(myFunc, (i+1)*1000, o));
```

So, `(i+1)*1000` set the timeouts to run i seconds after the call to forEach ends. For your code, change 1000 to 10000.

Of course if you don't want a delay for the first one, just do `i*1000`.

Also note that I'm putting `o` as the last parameter in `setTimeout`. The way you have it now, the function being called by `setTimeout` is the result of calling `myfunc` not `myfunc` itself.